# Backbone events hash with collections

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-events, backbone-views

Im trying to utilize Backbone's view events hash to bind a change event to the current view's collection:

```
events: {
    'this.collection change': 'render'
}
```

as opposed to my current method:

```
initialize: function() {
    this.collection.on('change', this.render, this);
}
```

but this does not seem to fire the event.  Are their limitations on binding events to collections using the events hash?

Comment: You can't short answer. What irk's you from doing the usual way

Answer (score 3):

```
events: {
    // hash
}
```

Is for hooking up your DOM events to your view functions.

```
this.collection.on('change', this.render, this);  // Except change is for models
```

in the initialization function is the way to do it, except the `change` event is for models and not collections, unless you have designated a custom change event for the collection that is properly triggered.

What you might be looking for is to bind an `add` `remove` or `reset` event to your collection.

Comment: If you have more details as to what you're trying to accomplish with your collection and view, if you spell it out I can probably tailor my answer to better solve your problem in context.

Answer (score 0):

If you were using Marionette views, you can use `collectionEvents` in the way you mentioned.  See http://marionettejs.com/docs/marionette.view.html#viewmodelevents-and-viewcollectionevents.

```
collectionEvents: {
    'change': 'render'
}
```

If you're using plain Backbone, orangewarp's suggestion of listening to the collection's `change` event using `this.collection.on` is the way to go.